# How to get commands and arguments from ps command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ps

I want to parse the output of a `ps -ef` command in order to display the command names and their arguments. I have two options that will display the command names:

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $8}'
```

or

```
ps -efo comm
```

However, neither of these will also display the arguments. Is there a way to do this without doing

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $8 $9 $10 ....}'
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ps` like this:

```
ps -eo command
```

Comment: Or else: `ps -eo args`